# How to do 301 redirection?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried doing 301 using a PHP code where old URL will go to new URL.

But it is not working as I am getting multiple 404 issues.

Please suggest me how do I do the 301 redirections.

**UPDATE:**

```
Redirect 301 /training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course http://www.example.com/ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course
```

It is showing 302 status code. What Should I do?

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Redirect 301 /training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course http://www.mercurysolutions.co/ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course

It is showing 302 status code. What Should I do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Include your entire `.htaccess` file. If you are seeing a 302 status code then there is _something else_ triggering the redirect, not the code you have posted.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I see a 301 redirect from "training" to "ec-council".

Comment: Yes, there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try add header

```
  header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,301);
```

Comment: Hii,

Header( “HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently” );

Header( “Location: http://www.new.com” );

Tried, But still showing 302 status code.

Comment: Maybe another php script run before you or  in webserver add header 302

Comment: Then it's better to configure in your webserver.